# How do I add new tab into SharePoint Search 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, search-results

[image]

I would like to know How I can add Intranet tab next to everything tab

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to Site settings > Search Settings as below:

URL - `https://sitecollectionurl/_layouts/15/enhancedSearch.aspx?level=site`

[image]

2) On the Search Settings page, in the Configure Search Navigation section, click Add Link.

[image]

3) In the Navigation Link dialog box, in the Title field, enter the search vertical title. This text will appear as the “tab” name on your search results page.
In my scenario, I entered Art.

[image]

4) In the URL field, select Browse and select a page for your search vertical.
In my scenario, I selected a custom sharepoint page.

[image]

5) Click OK to close the Navigation Link dialog Box.

6) Click OK, you can move it up or down as per requirement.

[image]